# How to get values out of object in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I have a javascript that is collecting data like this:

```
var chk = [];
$("input[name=row_sel]:checked").each(function() {
    chk.push ({
            "value": $(this).attr('id'),
            "type" : $(this).data('typo')
    });                 
});// JavaScript Document
```

The chk array is beeing sent via ajax into a php script
How can I interpret that array?

I have tried to do like this:

```
$chk = $_REQUEST['chk'];
foreach ($chk as $info) {
}
```

The ajax that is sending the array is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'view/debts/debts_validation.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'chk[]' : chk },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#dt_debts_processing").css("visibility","visible");
    },  
    complete: function() {
        $("#dt_debts_processing").css("visibility","hidden");
        $("#dt_debts_processing").html('Checking compatibility...');
    },                                  
    success: function(json) {
        if (json['status']) {
            location = '?route=home/debts/insert';
            cForm.hide().append('body').submit();
            return false;
        } else {
            $.sticky("Current selection is not available for multiple edit.", {autoclose : 5000, position: "top-right", type: "st-error" });
        }
    }                           
});
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to inspect the variable.

Comment: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'[object Object]'</font> <i>(length=15)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'[object Object]'</font> <i>(length=15)</i>
</pre>

Comment: Well if you show the code that send the data to the php script we would have half a chance at giving you some help. I only know one person who can look over your shoulder from 1000 miles away, and it not any of us.

Comment: As @Tim Rücker mentioned, you need to serialize objects before sending them to the backend, otherwise Javascript will convert the object to string (which becomes `[object Object]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to send an JavaScript object via ajax.

You cant do that. You need to serialize your object with the `JSON.stringify()` function.

Then you can reserialize this string with the `json_decode()` function.

I hope that helps.

**PS:**

Dont access the Request-Data with the `$_REQUEST` variable. Use `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: Was about to do a submit when I saw your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it should of been logic, using JSON.stringify(chk) did the job

Comment: I am aware of the $_REQUEST usage, but it is only in development

Answer (score 1):

this?

```
data: { 'chk[]' : chk },
```

you can perfectly send it like:

```
data: { chk : chk },
```

and access the array via:

```
$chk = $_POST['chk'];
foreach ($chk as $info) {
    echo "value: ".$info["value"];
    echo "type: ".$info["type"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
$chk = $_REQUEST['chk'];
    foreach ($chk as $info) {
        echo $info;
    }
```

Comment: Tried that and the output was '[object Object][object Object]'